# how to read the content in a pdf , so that it helps to find the footer and place the signature content above that in angular

Tags: angular, pdf, angular15

i am unable to find the source how to place my content inside the pdf at last page above footer

the container below the pdf should add in pdf at last page on above green color footer content.

[image]

Comment: You could insert the signature directly at a position equal to the (document height - footer - signature) using an annotation. For example, the LEADTOOLS toolkit code [here](https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/document-converter/automatically-merge-annotate-bookmark-pdf-files-leadtools/) under "Add Footer Annotations" can be modified to account for the footer. Other approaches you could try with LEADTOOLS is to use image processing to find the green check, or parse the PDF text to find any text with style or font unique to the footer. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)